# Dashboard - map that shows rig locations and wells

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dashboard

I've been experimenting with different dashboards. JDASH for example. I need to come up with something that shows different locations in Canada and US and show how many wells are at these locations and on these dates. 
Any ideas on how the easiest way would be to go about achieving this?
I have the database setup with all the user input information.. locations, gps cords etc... just need to know how to put that on a map

Comment: you can simply use google maps.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be achieved with [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/help-file/pivot_grid.htm#Pivot_Grid_Maps), you need to look into the Pivot grid element and use the map in there, the map accepts anything from GPS coordinates to city/country names, you just need to create a query from your database.

If you feel like using a full reporting/dashboarding solution is an overkill, you may be able to do the same with Bing or Google maps using their Javascript APIs.